# Create and access class instances from tkinter button presses

Tags: python, class, tkinter, methods

What I wish to do is create an instance of a class when I push one tkinter button, and then be able to access methods from that same instance when I interact with other tkinter buttons.

I have code for controlling a power supply unit (PSU), which includes of a class called `PowerSupply`. I won’t show everything here, but this includes an `__init__` method within this class to initialise the various attributes, a method `connect` to search for and connect to the PSU, and a method `onstate` to turn the PSU output On of Off (logic 1 or 0). It also uses the library `pyvisa`

```
import pyvisa    
class PowerSupply:

   def __init__(self):
    """Initialise attributes"""
    self.name = ""
    self.source_state = 0  # Output On/Off state

def connect(self):
    """Connect to SMU"""
    rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()  # Set up resource manager
    resource_list = rm.list_resources()  # List of available instruments
    Yoko_str = "0x0B21::0x001E"  # VISA ID should contain this string
    Yokogawa = [i for i, s in enumerate(resource_list) if Yoko_str in s]

    if len(Yokogawa) == 0:
        print("No Yokogawa supplies detected")
    else:
        ID = resource_list[Yokogawa[0]]
        self.name = rm.open_resource(ID)  # Open connection
        print("Yokogawa supply detected")

def onstate(self, state):
    """Turn SMU On or Off"""
    self.source_state = str(state)  # Update source state attribute
    self.name.write(":OUTPUT " + self.source_state)  # Send command
```

This seems to work perfectly fine, as I can connect and switch on/off the instrument. For example this code will create an instance '''smu''', connect to the instrument and turn it on:

```
    smu = PowerSupply()
    smu.connect()
    smu.onstate(1)
```

What I want to do next is have one tkinter button create the instance `smu` and connect to the PSU, and have a different tkinter button use the `onstate` method from this instance to turn the PSU on/off.

My "Connect" button code is:

```
btn_connect_dev = tk.Button(device_con_frame, text="Connect to Devices",
                            font=("Ariel", 11), command=connect_devices)
```

Which executes the function `connect_devices()`, itself:

```
def connect_devices():
    smu = PowerSupply()
    smu.connect()
    return smu
```

My "On/Off" button code:

```
btn_on_off = tk.Button(smu_ctrl_frame, text="Ouput ON/OFF", font=("Ariel", 11), command= smu.onstate(1))
```

But this gives me an error at that line `NameError: name 'smu' is not defined`

This I don't understand, because the instance `smu` should be returned by the `connect_devices()` function. I guess that `smu` is not available to the other button, but I have no idea why not or how to make it so, any advice would be great.

Comment: The return value of commands is not used / is not assigned to anything. You could define `smu` as a global variable.

Comment: @Wups Thanks. Using a global variable did occur to me, but I've also seen that using global variables is generally not a good idea in Python (because when code gets more complicated you could easily overwrite something?).

I'll give your suggestion a try, but I'd be interested to hear if there's another way.

Comment: I attempted to use a global variable but failed. I changed ```connect_devices``` to:

    def connect_devices():
       global smu
       smu = PowerSupply()
       smu.connect()


But still get the error ```NameError: name 'smu' is not defined``` as before

Comment: If you have a class for the buttons / interface, making smu an instance variable would be a better solution.

Comment: @Wups I'm new to Python so sorry if this sounds dumb, but do you mean I need to create a class for every different type of button in the GUI as well as for the instruments? That seems like a very complicated solution (if I understood correctly) as I have many other buttons in the GUI of different types!

I got something working using a global variable by the way, my previous issue was from importing commands from a different file.

Comment: You can simply create an instance of `PowerSupply` on program start, then you can use this instance in other parts of your program.  Also `command=smu.onstate(1)` should be `command=lambda: smu.onstate(1)` instead.